# Edittext null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I'm having trouble getting the text from a EditText. This EditText is inside a costum dialog created named optional. I supposed this as something to do with the views but still cannot figure it out.

Thank you for the help.

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.comments);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

            dialog.setTitle("Comentários");

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.optional);

            final EditText editTextName = (EditText) arg0.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            final EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) arg0.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
            final EditText editTextCompany = (EditText) arg0.findViewById(R.id.editTextCompany);

            Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            Button submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Null pointer exception
                    name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                    email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    company = editTextCompany.getText().toString();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**optional.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="com.example.isqsurvey.MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewEmail"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextCompany"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCompany"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/submit" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all your initialize to

```
 final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
 final EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
 final EditText editTextCompany = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextCompany);
```

This is because the views belong to the dialog layout optional.xml